# How to make functions execute synchronously in javascript? or how to make functions execute one after another?

Tags: javascript, closures

Here is my function

```
function two(){
    console.log('two')

}

function one(callback){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log('one')        
    },2000)
    callback()
}

one(two)
```

Actual output:

```
two  
one
```

My expected Output:

```
one  
two
```

My question is how to make changes to these functions so that function two() will be executed after function one()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply call the `callback()` in your `setTimeout`'s anonymous function like so:

```js
function two() {
  console.log('two')
}

function one(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('one');
    callback(); // execute callback after everything in setTimeout is executed
  }, 2000);
}
one(two);
```

... or, instead, you can use a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) with ES7's [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) (or using a `.then()` callback) capabilities like so:

```js
function two() {
  console.log('two')
}

async function one(callback) { // make async so we can use `await`
  await new Promise((resolve, rej) => { // wait for the promise to resolve ... 
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('one');
      resolve();
    }, 2000)
  });
  callback(); // ... then execute the callback
}
one(two);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
let one = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
  setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log('one')
      resolve(true)
  },2000)
})


one.then((value) => {
    console.log('two')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think callback will be called before other execution.This also works.

```
    function two(){
        console.log('two')
    }

    function one(one, callback){
        console.log(one);
        callback()
    }

    one('one', two);
```